# Stream multiple files with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send multiple video files with `express` and `mediaserver`.
Is there a way to check if a file has finished streaming and then change the video to the next one?
Below is the express request.
So to clarify I can send a video over with the below request but I do not know how to change the file once it has finished streaming, I read that `mediaserver` is great at sending media files but there aren't any docs, so I could not find a way or a description of how to do this.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const ms = require('mediaserver');

app.get('/video', function(req, res){
   const filename = 'sample1.mp4'
   const filename1 = 'sample2.mp4'
   ms.pipe(req, res, assetsPath + filename);
   console.log ('[streaming video]: ' + filename);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
   console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
});
```

Comment: Why not creating another request when the first streaming finished? One request per file?

Comment: @MartinAdámek I've been trying to avoid one request per file as it will soon become unmanageable due to large number of files.

Comment: You could use `concat` to append another file to the stream, not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: @MartinAdámek I'm assuming that would mean the video would now be 2 videos in one, if like to keep them separate so there is clear definition between each video. Thanks for the idea though, I'll have a look into it

Comment: Well that's the reason why I suggested making separate requests. I do not think that it is a problem. It's common pattern of handling such a thing.

Comment: @MartinAdámek ok, I get that but it seems odd to me that there isn't another way around. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to dynamically host files that I could find is to have a generic 'streaming' route and then pass the file as a query:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const app = express();
const ms = require('fs'); 

app.get('/stream', function(req,res){
    var fileId = req.query.id,
    file = __dirname + fileId;
    fs.exists(file,function(exists){
        if(exists) {
            console.log("[Streaming:] %s", file);
            var rstream = fs.createReadStream(file); 
            rstream.pipe(res);
        } else {
            console.log("[ERROR Streaming:] %s", file);
            res.send("Playback 404");
            res.end();
        }
    });
}); 

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
});
```

You can then look through a directory and create a html string to send to the page, creating a button that streams the files on click:

```
var serverAddress = "http://localhost:3000"
var file = "sample.mp4"
stream = "<a href='" +serverAddress+ "/stream?id=" + file + "' target='_blank'><button class='btn btn-success'>Stream</button></a>";
res.send (stream)
```